# ios : In-call status bar issue

Tags: ios

I have an application (App1) where there is a simple page, whenever there is an incoming call the status bar shows on the top.
I want to make it shift the application down instead of showing it on the application top.

I created one app(App2) sometime back and in that the status bar pushes the view down but I am not able to understand why it does not happen for the new application(App1) I created. I am sure I did not write any code in the application(App2) to handle such scenarios or to listen such notifications. Both the apps are for ios7 and use XIBs. The App2 has a login page and then it shows Tab Bar, for both the pages the view is shifted down whenever there is a call in progress.

Any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: As you said App2 has tabbar which automatically adjusts itself as per your view bounds when the call comes.

Comment: It is not about Tabbar, even if it is showing the Login view which is not tabbar, App2 adjusts itself